# Examples for pre-emptive and non-preemptive resources in OS

Tags: resources, operating-system, preemptive

According to my understanding, In Operating Systems **Preemptive resources** are those which can be taken away from a process without causing any ill effects to the process, while **non-pre-emptive resources** are those which cannot be taken away from the process without causing any ill effects.

I am interested in knowing examples of these pre-emptive and non-pre-emptive resources, in TWO separate categories i.e Hardware Resources and Softwares Resources.

Generally when people give examples it is these Hardware Resources, but I am not sure about the examples w.r.t Software Resources.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is best fitted for `cs.stackexchange.com` !

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful you are right. So how can this question be migrated to `cs.stackexchange.com` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best fitted for `cs.stackexchange.com` !

Answer (score 3):

Memory is an example of a preemptive resource, as that is one of the main resources processes dread to share..
A printer is an example of a non-preemptive resource, as when a process has been granted access to it, a process must finished in operations without being interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft were using non-preemptive till windows 3.x whereas Apple started using Preemptive from OS X.